# Is there a package for translating incidence matrices to electric circuits?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is there a way to take a given incidence matrix and translate it to an image of a an electrical circuit? For example in TikZ or some other package. For the background of this: I am working with an e-learning tool, and am given a few incidence matrices, I am looking for a solution that has a random matrix as input and an image (or a TikZ code) as an output.

An incidence matrix is defined here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix

Why is this connected with electrical circuits:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/network_theory/network_theory_topology.htm

Since we can represent the circuits as graphs and the topology of graphs can be represented with an incidence matrix, I was curious if there is a possibility (with TeX, this is why I posted here) to „generate“ a diagram of a circuit with an already given incidence matrix.

I am just curious if this can work, or already exists.

Comment: Can you please point to an example/add a minimal example to the question? I do not know what an incidence matrix is (at least under that name) and what it means to generate a circuit from it.

Comment: You realize that drawing an incidence matrix is nearly as difficult as drawing a circuit, the main difference is the use of curved paths and putting components in series into a single path.  OTOH, neither is particularly difficult in itself.

Comment: are you referring to this -- -https://basicelectronicsguide.blogspot.com/2018/07/incidence-matrix.html

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: This is much more graph theory than circuits --- ok, so now I know the answer: no, no that I know. I would explore this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39511179/2907484 (using NetworkX https://networkx.org/)